# Doctrine Query order by sum

Tags: sql, doctrine, dql

I have a query where i want to order for a subselect which is an addition

```
$this->queryObj = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('l.*')
    ->addSelect('(SELECT count(*) FROM LeagueMatch m LEFT JOIN m.UserA a LEFT JOIN m.UserB b WHERE m.league_id = ? AND m.user_id_a=l.user AND m.result_accepted=1 AND m.isOneOnOneMatch = true OR m.league_id = ? AND m.user_id_b=l.user AND m.isOneOnOneMatch = true AND m.result_accepted=1) as numberofmatches')
    ->addSelect('(SELECT sum(m4.result_a) FROM LeagueMatch m4 
                  LEFT JOIN m4.UserA a4 
                  LEFT JOIN m4.UserB b4
                  WHERE m4.league_id = ? AND m4.user_id_a=l.user AND m4.isOneOnOneMatch = true AND m4.result_accepted=1) as winresults1')
    ->addSelect('(SELECT sum(m5.result_b) FROM LeagueMatch m5 
                  LEFT JOIN m5.UserA a5 
                  LEFT JOIN m5.UserB b5
                  WHERE m5.league_id = ? AND m5.user_id_b=l.user AND m5.isOneOnOneMatch = true AND m5.result_accepted=1) as winresults2')
    ->where('l.league = ?', $id)
    ->from('LeagueUser l')->orderBy('(winresults1 + winresults2) DESC')->execute(array(HERE_ARE_MY_VALUES));
```

This part "orderBy('(winresults1 + winresults2) " is not working and i do not know why.
Its not showing me an error, the syntax is ok but my result is not order for wresult 1 + 2

Comment: shouldn't you add the respective alias to `orderBy('(winresults1 + winresults2)...`

Comment: still need help. some ideas here?

Comment: I think what @samura was trying to say is that you should use m5.winresults1 + m5.winresults2 (or whatever the correct table alias is) in order to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: i still sit on this problem. m5.winresults shows me:Couldn't find class m5 - do really need help

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Not sure that it works, but occurred me ;)

```
$this->queryObj = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('l.*')
    ->addSelect('(SELECT count(*) FROM LeagueMatch m LEFT JOIN m.UserA a LEFT JOIN m.UserB b WHERE m.league_id = ? AND m.user_id_a=l.user AND m.result_accepted=1 AND m.isOneOnOneMatch = true OR m.league_id = ? AND m.user_id_b=l.user AND m.isOneOnOneMatch = true AND m.result_accepted=1) as numberofmatches')
    ->addSelect('(SELECT sum(m4.result_a) as total FROM LeagueMatch m4 
                  LEFT JOIN m4.UserA a4 
                  LEFT JOIN m4.UserB b4
                  WHERE m4.league_id = ? AND m4.user_id_a=l.user AND m4.isOneOnOneMatch = true AND m4.result_accepted=1) as winresults1')
    ->addSelect('(SELECT sum(m5.result_b) as total FROM LeagueMatch m5 
                  LEFT JOIN m5.UserA a5 
                  LEFT JOIN m5.UserB b5
                  WHERE m5.league_id = ? AND m5.user_id_b=l.user AND m5.isOneOnOneMatch = true AND m5.result_accepted=1) as winresults2')
    ->where('l.league = ?', $id)
    ->from('LeagueUser l')->orderBy('(winresults1.total + winresults2.total) DESC')->execute(array(HERE_ARE_MY_VALUES));
```